# git checkout revision -- *partial/path*? (i.e. use pathspec with git checkout from specific commit)

Tags: git

To checkout any file with "partial/path" in its path+name from HEAD:

```
git checkout *partial/path*
```

To checkout files from specific commits (the `--` is optional here):

```
git checkout abcde -- full/path/to/my/file full/path/to/another/file
```

Counterintuitively, the following command does **not** checkout files matching the pathspec in the specifed commit:

```
git checkout abcde -- *partial/path*
```

Instead, it results in `error: pathspec '*partial/path*' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

My question is: **Is it possible to use a pathspec to checkout multiple files using pathspec from a specific commit?**

---

**Note:** I realize that `git checkout branch file` is probably a completely different command from `git checkout pathspec` (and also completely different from `git checkout branch`), which may explain why pathspec doesn't work here.

**Note:** The following alias only partially solves the problem:

```
[alias] ccps = "!f() { git ls-files $2 | xargs -I {} git checkout $1 -- \"{}\"; }; f"
```

This fails when one or more files has been added or removed matching the pathspec between the current commit and the target commit.

---

**UPDATE:** The following alias (sort of) does what I want:

```
[alias] ccps = "!f() { git ls-tree -r --name-only $1 | grep $2 | xargs -I {} git checkout $1 -- {}; }; f"
```

Problems with this solution:

- `grep $2` is not the same as a pathspec (will not work with `.` and `..` and `*`).
- It is rather slow (it took ~5 seconds to sequentially `git checkout` 57 files returned from `grep`).

But at the same time, now I have access to regex, which is a plus.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are usually expanded by your *shell* against the live filesystem. To pass them directly to Git, either escape or quote the pathspec, i.e. `\*partial/path\*` or `"*partial/path*"`. That way, expansion will be done by git itself and against the given commit.

Comment: I don't think this is a shell expansion problem. Running `echo *` successfully triggers expansion and prints all of the files in the current directory. But running `echo *partial/path*` does not match anything and thus prints `*partial/path*`, which I expect is what ends up being passed to git.

Comment: I also tried `git checkout abcde -- "*partial/path*"`, which still gives `error: pathspec '*partial/path*' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: I thought it was working except matching the wrong files. Try '**partial/path*' if the wildcards are supposed to cross slashes; normally a * will only match exactly one level, not subdirectories.

Comment: No problem, Sorry, I wasn't clear about what the problem was with the command. I just updated the question a few minutes ago with the result.